# VBA add a number before a variable if matches certain conditions

Tags: vba, date

I am trying to update a weekly report. However for the calendar weeks between 1 and 9 i wish to attached 0 in-front.  So it shows "CW1- 14" instead of "CW1- 14" for example   I am trying to do it with if statesmen - so far unsuccessfully.

```
Dim week1 As String
week1 = Format(Date - 7, "ww")
'If week1 <= 9 Then
'week1 = Format(0, Date - 7, "ww")
'ElseIf week1 > 9 Then
'week1 = Format(Date - 7, "ww")
 'End If

 Dim long1 As String
long1 = Format(Date - 10, "yyyy")
Dim week2 As String
week2 = week1 - 4
Dim nameweek As String
nameweek = "CW" & week2 & " - " & "CW" & week1 & " " & long1
```

Comment: `format(Format(Date - 7, "ww"),"00")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Format()` twice.

```
Dim week1 As String
week1 = Format(Format(Date - 7, "ww"), "00")
' That would produce week1 = "01" or "09"
```